# If I have a parameter that changes of value at time 0 in GEKKO , will it actually change at 0 or at the next data point?

Tags: parameters, gekko

I have a GEKKO model to estimate parameters and I have a parameter defined as follows:

```
    step = [0 if z<0 else 1 for z in m.time]
    m_param = m.Param(step)
```

However, my array m.time does not contain 0, i.e, it might be [-20, 30, 60]. So I want to know if m_param will actually change the value at time 0 or at time 30 (next data point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `m.time=[-20,30,60]`, the values of `m_param` are `[0,1,1]`. The causes a change at `t=30` where it corresponds to the time value in `m.time`. You would need to include a time point at zero to have the switch occur at that point.

```py
m.time = [-20,0,30,60]
step = [0 if z<0 else 1 for z in m.time]
m_param = m.Param(step)
```